# Is it a way to check whether all the subpaths of the current request.path have a view callable associated with?

Tags: python, pyramid

I am working on a breadcrumbs generator.
It uses request.path and then, for each subpath, builds a breadcrumb.

Example:

```
/blog/articles/view/12345
```

Then for each of the subpaths:

```
/blog/articles/view
/blog/articles
/blog
```

True would be returned, if there's a view callable behind this URL ( allowing GET method without arguments ), otherwise False

So that I could make the subpaths in the breadcrumbs clickable to show that there's something served there.

Any idea which would not call any of the subpaths and generate useless code execution?

Comment: So, I see, someone doing a down vote, fair enough, but without any explanation, which is definitely not helping at all.

Comment: Likely because you don't share a bit of code to show what you have tried.

Comment: @Tshepang: In this case, it's not straightforward actually, I don't think the downvote is deserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to test all path prefixes; routing allows for many, arbitrary URLs to be possible. Moreover, with path predicates in the mix, multiple routes could match the same URL and choosing between them depends on other information from the request.

To prepare your breadcrumbs, instead loop over the sub-paths *once* and determine for each if there is a matching view; the easiest way to do this is to reuse the code underlying the `pviews` command; this code needs the current request:

```
from pyramid.scripts.pviews import PViewsCommand

pvcomm = PViewsCommand()

urlpath = request.environ['PATH_INFO']
parts = urlpath.split('/')
existing_views = {}

for i in range(1, len(parts)):
    path = '/'.join(parts[:i])
    view = pvcomm._find_view(path, request.registry)
    if view is not None:
        existing_views[path] = view
```

You can now look up path prefixes in the `existing_views` dictionary.

Comment: Awesome Martijn!
I was testing with request.Blank() and DummyRequests, which where doing real http request to each views or 404 when none.
Let me test this and I'll validate the answer once I finish the test.

Comment: @AnthonyPerot-Rajan: That's why reusing the `PViewsCommand` class is so much better; it does create a dummy request for you but takes care not to actually invoke the view.